# Movie about a crashed UFO that drove radio frequencies crazy and gave people physical symptoms

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, ufos

I saw this movie in the early 2000s, but it was definitely a little older, possibly from the 1980s or '90s. Most likely a children's scifi film.

I remember there was a UFO that crashed and the frequencies from that UFO were driving the radio frequencies crazy, and giving people physical symptoms. I think the main characters lived on a farm. If not, it was definitely a country town. I would like to say it was similar to, or possibly based on, the UFO event in Berkshire, Massachusetts.

The physical symptoms that I can remember were hearing high pitch sounds to the point people's ears bled.

They either didn't know it was a UFO at first and were searching for the source of the strange events, or the main characters did and were trying to keep anyone searching for it from it. Either way there was definitely a government official asking questions at various parts and trying to follow them. I'm not entirely certain if there were any actual aliens as characters.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE. If you peruse through [this checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) and happen to remember any extra details, please [edit] them in. No detail is too insignificant.

Answer (score 3):

I've only just speed-watched it, but other than being earlier than your guess, there seem to be a lot of similarities to the 1967 movie [*Night of the Big Heat*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062037/).  A very detailed [plot synopsis](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062037/plotsummary#synopsis) covers most of the details you mention.

Some notes from a quick viewing of the movie:

- The story supposedly takes place on an island, but except for a few shots of the beach, it looks more like rural England with an inn more or less on its own.
- The presence of the aliens creates an area of barely tolerable and growing heat, and the people increasingly suffer from it.
- The appearances of the aliens are accompanied by a high-pitched sound.
- This sound is cripplingly loud when the aliens are close.
- The movie starts out with a scientist, Hanson, setting automated cameras to catch pictures of whatever is causing the strange phenomena.
- The phones, radio and TV all go out due to interference, and the radar station is destroyed.
- People are generally affected by the heat produced by the aliens, and killed by it when the aliens get too close to them.
- The aliens only ever appear as glowing lights, mostly off-screen.
- The "government official" might have been Hanson, the scientist, who suspects more than anyone else. He is poking around trying to find evidence, but from the point of view of the others he is acting suspiciously.
- Figuring out that aliens were causing the electrical interference, noises, and unexplained deaths and fires took up a significant part of the movie, and finding where they had landed to try to drive them away was the climactic point.

Depending on your location, you may be able to watch the entire movie on YouTube:

The biggest difference to what you recall seems to be that, while the high-pitched noise made people clutch at their ears to block it out, I didn't see anyone's ears actually *bleed*.  (Though the noise was strong enough that one person drove off the road and crashed and another dropped a torch causing a fire because the sound was so painful.)

Comment: I'm definitely going to check this out. Might be it. I will let you know. Thank you!

Comment: No this isn't it. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you are looking for a movie. There was a good series on CBS called ***[Threshold](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460686/)*** (2005-2006). The premise was:

From [TV Guide](https://www.tvguide.com/tvshows/threshold/1030352367/):

> Dr. Molly Caffrey, a government contingency analyst, investigates the arrival of aliens who threaten Earth in this sci-fi thriller. A mysterious spacecraft appears near a Navy cargo freighter in the Atlantic Ocean and emits a deadly, piercing sound that kills most of the crew. Those who don't die mutate into aliens who then attempt to infect others. Molly assembles an expert team that includes a microbiologist, a physicist, a covert operative and an expert in languages and math to stop them.

This seems to meet your criteria.

Comment: When quoting a synopsis, it's good to provide a link to show where the quote was taken from. Also, if you type `>` directly before a quote, it will separate that portion of text as a block quote, making it more distinct from standard text.

Comment: No it was definitely a movie and involved a UFO that crashed. I remember the scene of seeing the UFO smoking and sparking in the ground